# Implementing OAUth 2.0 in Android app communicating with Web API

Tags: android, .net, api, oauth

I'm new to OAuth 2.0 and I want to know how to use it in my project.

What I understood from articles I read, Android app (which is the client) sends username,password in request asking for token, server make sure credentials are valid and returns a token to client.
What I'm missing is the best practice on server to validate the credentials, should I make it simple and (check credentials -> create token -> send it to user) or there's simple library creates the token for me and handle the redirects to another controller... etc.
can I know the following:
 1. Which .NET library out there can I use to simplify the process for
    me?.
 2. Does Android App need any extra lib to use with this? or it just have to send the requests?.
 3. There's server, client and resource libraries I saw. what each one do (like in Thinktecture libraries).

Thanx

Comment: It's kind of a complex question which involves more parts. Try braking it up in parts. But, I am facing the same unknowns as you describe. Any luck since?

Comment: Not yet actually I got buzy with other things